# Rabbitmq MQTT topic rights

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ 3.6.12.

Users are connecting thought MQTT and writing to different topics.
How is it possible to restrict MQTT user rights to specific topics?

Currently everything is allowed:
[image]

I am aware of this documentation, but honestly I cant figure out, what to set:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

I tried to set "my-test-topic" in write regexp, but then the client gets disconnected when it tries to write to this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an solution. The following configuration will allow the user to write/read only to topics that start with ex-foo

[image]